# How to give shadow to a box in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am using rectangular box to show some imageView in it.I want to give box outer shadow like this [image]

I am using this xml content

```
<corners android:radius="3dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#AAAAAA" />

<solid android:color="#FFF" />
```

and getting this box
[image]

Could anybody please tell how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

use 9-patch to make a proper background

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 2):

I used the tutorial and the images from the following link and it gave me a perfect shadow, (I just had to adjust the paddings to my likings):
http://sapandiwakar.in/adding-shadows-to-views-in-android-using-9-patch-image/

Just add the shadow to the parent view and your regular background on top of that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_menu_background">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewMenu"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't add shadows via code / xml in Android, unless you want to start overriding onDraw, and manually draw a shadow (which probably won't give you great results, will be computationally expensive and not really worth the time if you ask me).

You'll need to go with a 9-patch solution for this.

I feel your pain though... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code,
I have done it using two layout but you can merge it to to one

in your xml file write this code

```
     <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/home_screen"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_border" >                  

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"                        
                    android:background="@drawable/home_border" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/menu_background" />

                </LinearLayout>    

     </RelativeLayout>


 and the two xml in res/drawable is here

  home_border.xml 

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
   </shape>
</item>

<item android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp"  
    android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
           <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
         <corners
         android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
     android:topRightRadius="1dp"/>
    </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>


and background_border.xml

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
   <item android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp"  android:top="-10dp"  
       android:bottom="-10dp">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="#884d4d4d" />
         <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
      </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

try this. here #884d4d4d is the color code for your transparent color is a combination of two color transparent and gray